# What is Pixel 1 Latency in Tensorflow object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How is Pixel 1 latency different from speed (ms) in [Tf object detection pretrained models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) benchmarking?

Answer (score 2):

Pixel 1 latency : The speed when the model is run on a pixel 1 smartphone.

Pixel 1 is the name of the smartphone. So it gives you the type of processor on which the model was run.

I found the information from the table 4 of this paper

https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Sandler_MobileNetV2_Inverted_Residuals_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf